# Anaconda 3.5 (64bit Windows) Install cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, anaconda, cx-oracle

I have installed Anaconda 3.5 for Windows 64bits, and I need to connect to the Oracle database using package "cx_Oracle".

I tried with the anaconda way:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda cx_oracle
```

The error messages below:

```
Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - cx_oracle
  - python 3.5*
Use 'conda info cx_oracle' etc. to see the dependencies for each package.
Note that the following features are enabled:
  - vc14
```

It seems that cx_oracle isn't compatible with Python 3.5.

After this, I also tried to install directly with the binary:

```
python setup.py install
```

It throws a bunch of errors like:

```
cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol OCILobGetChunkSize
cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol OCIStmtExecute
cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol OCILobFileClose
```

Is there a way to install cx_oracle for Anaconda 3.5 ??

Comment: Try to download and pip install `cx_Oracle-5.2+oci12c-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_oracle

Comment: Hi Gohlke, Thanks for your comment. I successfully installed it using the wheel file. However, when I try my script, it throws an error message below:        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testDB.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable. (The specified procedure cannot be found.)

Comment: In addition to my comment, I have installed oracle client 11.2.0.3, and the paths are in the system variable Path: C:\oracle\ora_client\bin
C:\oracle\product\64bit\11.2.0.3.0\bin

Comment: The binaries require Oracle version 12.1, not 11.2.

Comment: I tried this also: downloaded Oracle client 12.1, put the unziped folder in Anaconda folder, and added it into Path.  But it still didn't work....

Comment: Has anyone solved this yet, similar issue with Anaconda 4.0.0 Python 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of non-trivial. However doable. Follow these steps:

**1) Download Oracle Instant client for Windows x64 from**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

e.g. choose client e.g. 11.2.0.4

-> instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

-> instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip

**2) Create directory and unzip the client & sdk in there:**

e.g. c:\ora\11gx64

**3) Set ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN**

See https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10 for details

e.g. *ORACLE_HOME=c:\ora\11gx64*

and *TNS_ADMIN=c:\ora\11gx64*

also add %ORACLE_HOME% in Your %PATH%

**4) In the created directory put file tnsnames.ora and fill with connection string to db:**

%ORACLE_HOME%**tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

-> replace 127.0.0.1 with your hostname

-> replace XE with your SID

**5) I suppose You've got already Python installed.**

-> Otherwise visit Download page for Python

-> Install python (3.6.1 in the time of writting)

-> If not installed install pip (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip)

-> execute *python get-pip.py*

**6) Download and Install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools**

-> Search for Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools
  -> Install visualcppbuildtools_full.exe

**7) Use pip to install cx_oracle**

```
  pip install cx_oracle
```

(in the time of writing there is trouble with default installed version 5.3 so the Version 6.0b2 has to be installed)

```
  python -m pip install cx_Oracle --pre
```

The first steps are universal in my honest opinion for both conda and pip.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install cx_oracle from pip3 or conda either. Got it working eventually by downloading the installer for windows 64 from pypi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/